# More efficient algorithm(s) for performing a "largest value smaller than X" lookup

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

I have an event-driven application that needs to do something like the following, where the `handle_event()` function is called any time an event is received:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Event:
    event_id: int
    occurrence_time: datetime
    processing_time: datetime

    def __post_init__(self) -> None:
        if self.occurrence_time > self.processing_time:
            raise ValueError("Impossible event! An event can never be processed before it occurs.")


_all_events: list[Event]

def handle_event(curr_event: Event) -> None:
    past_events = (e in _all_events if e.occurrence_time < curr_event.occurrence_time)
    try:
        prev_event = max(
            prev_events, key=lambda e: (e.occurrence_time, e.processing_time),
        )
    except ValueError:  # "ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence"
        prev_event = None

    _all_events.append(curr_event)
    do_something(prev_event, curr_event)
```

Is there something I can do to reduce the time complexity of this algorithm? I am open to changing how `all_events` is stored, using some kind of caching/memoization, storing data in some kind of separate index data structure, etc.

---

My system has the following characteristics:

- Events arrive into my system order of processing time, not occurrence time. Therefore I know that `all_events` will always be sorted by processing time.
- The majority of events (let's say it's around 70 – 90%) arrive correctly ordered with respect to occurrence time, but the remainder arrive late, meaning that they arrive after several other records with later occurrence times. These are fundamental characteristics of the system and they cannot be changed.
- Likewise, the business logic inside the `do_something()` function is fundamentally a recursive algorithm, and also cannot be changed to work differently. Assume for the sake of this exercise that every call of `do_something()` takes 1 millisecond.
- There is only one event-handling process, so we can ignore any concerns about concurrency.

This all works well enough, except when `all_events` gets big. This lookup is very inefficient in the most-common case of records arriving approximately in order of occurrence time, and it ends up being very expensive when there are a lot of events already stored. Specifically, if most events arrive in order of occurrence time, I will end up scanning most or all of the `all_events` list for every single event. This

In testing on real data at realistic scale, this procedure becomes dysfunctionally slow, taking *several days* to process ~1 million events in CPython 3.11 on a modestly-sized VPS. I believe I have written an ["accidentally quadratic"](https://accidentallyquadratic.tumblr.com/) algorithm, and with a large number of records I am in an extremely steep region of the parabola.

I happen to be using Python here, but this question is meant to be more conceptual than about anything specific to Python.

**Note**: In my real application, the `all_events` list is stored in a database that auto-magically partitions and indexes the data to support this kind of task (TimescaleDB). However, I am **not** looking for solutions that depend on access to any particular database. I want to focus on this problem from **an algorithmic and conceptual perspective**, rather than relying on any pre-existing database feature/index/optimization that might exist. I occasionally need to implement similar logic *without* the benefit of access to such a database, and I want to avoid writing wildly inefficient code.

Comment: It seems `handle_event` needs to do two things: insert `curr_event` into storage and `do_something` with it along with the event with the largest `occurrence_time` that comes before it. You could store events into a balanced binary search tree where the key compared is `occurrence_time`, so that the insertion and retrieval in `handle_event` are done in logarithmic time. You'll likely need to take special care in handling events that have the same `occurrence_time` if this case is possible, however.

Comment: @wLui155 that seems like the start of a useful answer, if you're able to write that up.

Answer (score 1):

You could improve a bit by maintaining a (second?) list that is sorted by `occurrence_time`. For this you can benefit from `bisect`.

For instance:

```py
_all_events: list[Event]
_sorted_events: list[Event]

def handle_event(curr_event: Event) -> None:
    _all_events.append(curr_event)
    i = bisect_left(_sorted_events, curr_event.occurrence_time, 
                                    key=attrgetter('occurrence_time'))
    _sorted_events.insert(i, curr_event)
    prev_event = _sorted_events[i-1] if i else None 
    do_something(prev_event, curr_event)
```

To do even better, you could use a library that implements some kind of sorted container, like based on AVL tree, red-black tree, skip list, B-tree, ...etc.

For instance, with [`sortedcontainers`](https://pypi.org/project/sortedcontainers/):

```py
_all_events: list[Event]
_sorted_events = SortedList(key=attrgetter('occurrence_time'))

def handle_event(curr_event: Event) -> None:
    _all_events.append(curr_event)
    i = _sorted_events.bisect_left(curr_event)
    _sorted_events.add(curr_event)
    prev_event = _sorted_events[i-1] if i else None 
    do_something(prev_event, curr_event)
```